# Change value of selected cell from datagridview to zero (0)

Tags: c#, excel, database, datagridview

I have connection to an Excel file which displays in datagridview. I would like to change value of selected cell ind datagridview to "0" (zero) by clicking a button.

[image]
As you can see from pic, there is a button "Null cell" and selected one cell.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you merely want to change the value displayed on the `DataGridCell`, and not update the DB?

Comment: Are you saying you want the "Null cell" button to change it to zero or are you saying you want another button? Either way, the code behind that button should have most of what you need if it currently works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the code below. If you will select several cells than the button sets the value to zero only for the first cell.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];
    dataGridView1.Rows[selected.RowIndex].Cells[selected.ColumnIndex].Value = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! It helped!

Comment: Just one more question, is it possible to select more than one cell? @L_J

Comment: Sure, by default you can select as many cells as you want. To set value for each selected cells you can use something like this: `foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{   dataGridView1.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = 0;
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, SIR! You helped me a lot. @L_J